# Reading value from external ELF symbol in C

Tags: c, elf

I have following ELF symbol (defined in assembly file):

```
Disassembly of section .memory_info:

10000bb8 <__memory_info>:
10000bb8:   10000bd4    ldrdne  r0, [r0], -r4
10000bbc:   20000000    andcs   r0, r0, r0
10000bc0:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
10000bc4:   20000000    andcs   r0, r0, r0
10000bc8:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
10000bcc:   20000000    andcs   r0, r0, r0
10000bd0:   000000a8    andeq   r0, r0, r8, lsr #1
```

I want to read this value in C as structure.

I tried to do it in the following way:

```
typedef struct {
    void *flash_end;
    void *ram_text_begin;
    void *ram_text_size;
    void *ram_data_begin;
    void *ram_data_size;
    void *ram_bss_begin;
    void *ram_bss_size;
} memory_info_t;

int main() {
    extern memory_info_t __memory_info;
    uint32_t *a = __memory_info.flash_end;
    
    asm("bkpt #0");
}
```

But according to gdb actual value of a on breakpoint is not what I expected:

```
(gdb) print a
$1 = (uint32_t *) 0xffffffff
```

Comment: What does `(gdb) p &__memory_info` print?

Comment: @EmployedRussian `Missing ELF symbol "__memory_info"`. Also `x <address of __memory_info>` prints `0xffffffff`. Probably openocd does not load `.memory_info` section into memory. I will try to change section properties and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found a solution. I use openocd to load ELF images to flash memory. I turns out that openocd obviously does not load sections without segment. So I added SHF_ALLOC flag to .memory_info section to automatically assign it to segment.

Before:

```
.section .memory_info
```

After:

```
.section .memory_info, "a"
```

And it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Take a peek at the generated assembly code for main().   I think you will find that the statement     `uint32_t *a = __memory_info.flash_end;` generates no code, because there is no reason to generate this load.

If you change:

`extern memory_info_t __memory_info;`

to:

`extern volatile memory_info_t __memory_info;`

it will likely scare the compiler into leaving the dummy load alone, but the semantics of *volatile* started off muddy, and decayed over time.

Comment: Unfortunately, volatile does not change anything. I looked at the bytecode of the main function with and without `a` definition. `a` definition is actually generates some code.